# How to get audio buffer from video element api?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

How to get audio buffer from video element? i know a ways from BaseAudioContext.decodeAudioData(). it fetch directly from audio file via request. but i need to get the buffer from video directly to manipulate.

```js
const video = document.createElement('video');
video.src = 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4';
document.body.appendChild(video);

let audioCtx;
let audioSource;

const play = () => {

  audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  audioSource = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(video);
  audioSource.connect(audioCtx.destination);

  video.play()
};

video.ontimeupdate = () => {
  let buffer = new AudioBufferSourceNode(audioCtx);
  // Manipulate audio buffer realtime
  // Problem is buffer null
  buffer.connect(audioSource.context.destination);
  console.log(buffer.buffer)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
      <button onclick="play()">Play</button>
    </body>
</html>
```